# Add private pypi repository to Pycharm from GItlab

Tags: python, pycharm, gitlab, repository, pypi

I'm trying to connect PyCharm to a new gitlab repository we have on a local server. I have published a library package lets call package-name

I can use

```
pip install package-name --extra-index-url http://token:token_key@<server>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple --trusted-host <server>
```

using the terminal with my venv activated, and it will install without issue.

However, when I try that same URL inside of Pycharm>Settings>Project Interpreter> Add package > Manage Repositories > "URL HERE"

```
http://token:token_key@<server>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
```

I get errors (usually a 404 error which seems to indicate the url isn't found.) Why does it work one way and not the other? And more importantly how do I get it to work so I don't have to type in that long url each time I want to install a package from the repository?

How do you install a gitlab pypi style package registry (repository for packages) in pycharm?

Preferrably, I would be to find the package name in the list of packages sound in Settings> Python Interpreter>Add package (+) that includes both pypi and local packages together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue in PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26556).

A fix has been implemented in PyCharm 2022.1 (which has not yet been released, but is available for preview evaluation).